# image_tag in not using asset_host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In production, when I call image_tag inside a mailer view, the image url reflects the asset host that I've set. However, when I call `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag` in a module inside lib/ it does not reflect the asset host.

This is in the production environment.

**production.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.asset_host =
    config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new do |source|
      "https://mycustomhost.com"
    end
```

**production console:**

> irb(main):001:0>
>   ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("my_asset.jpg")
>   => ...src=\"/my_app/my_asset-b00c676835d609cc1aed3ce6e7018ee1.jpg\"..

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) suggests that I need to set the asset_host on `ActionController::Base`. I've tried both setting setting `ActionController::Base.asset_host` in the console/setting it in `production.rb` and restarting nginx, then running `ActionController::Base.image_tag`, but it still does not return the image url with the asset host.

Any ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work by getting `view_context` from the mailer, and calling the helper method on that. It doesn't explain why `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag` isn't reading from `asset_host` though, but since I'm essentially trying to replicate the behavior of `ActionView`'s `image_tag`, this approach seems better.